# Error when creating a function in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, select, where-clause, sql-function, stored-functions

I am trying to create a postgres function that just returns the friends that a user has in the database. It should just return the first and last names of all the user's friends. However, I keep getting this error:

`[42601] ERROR: query has no destination for result data`

It does not make sense to me because I am returning a table with all the first and last names.

Here is my function. Does anyone know why this would be the case? I could not find the answer anywhere else.

```
create or replace function getFriends(pEmail text)
    returns TABLE(pkUser int, FirstName text, LastName text)
    language plpgsql
as
$$
    declare pk int;
begin
    select "pkUser" into pk from users where "Email"=pEmail;

    select
           "pkUser", "FirstName", "LastName"
    from users u
    inner join friends f on u."pkUser" = f."User2ID"
    where f."User1ID"=pk;

    select "pkUser", "FirstName", u."LastName" 
    from users u 
    inner join friends f on u."pkUser" = (f."User1ID") 
    where f."User2ID"=pk;

end
$$;
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you for that link. I am trying to learn postgres through a  side project and coming from mysql. I appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plpgsql function should `return query` to be valid.

But here I think that you can do what you want with a straight query, so just switch to sql and :

```
create or replace function getFriends(pEmail text)
returns table(pkUser int, FirstName text, LastName text)
language sql
as
$$
    select u2."pkUser", u2."FirstName", u2."LastName"
    from users u1
    inner join friends f 
        on u1."pkUser" in (f."User1ID", f."User2ID")
    inner join users   u2 
        on  u2."pkUser" in (f."User1ID", f."User2ID")
        and u2."pkUser" <> u1."pkUser" 
    where u1."Email" = pEmail;
$$
```

This selects the record of the user whose email is given as an arugment to the function, then searches for all corresponding friends (whether in `User1ID` or `User2ID`) and finally return the friend user record.

Answer (score 1):

Your final query doesn't "consume" its result. in PL/pgSQL, the result of a query either needs to be stored into a variable (like you did in your first query) or discarded using `perform` or returned from the function. To do that, use `RETURN QUERY`.

You can combine both query using a UNION ALL

```
create or replace function getFriends(pEmail text)
    returns TABLE(pkUser int, FirstName text, LastName text)
    language plpgsql
as
$$
    declare pk int;
begin
    select "pkUser" into pk from users where "Email"=pEmail;

    return query

      select "pkUser", "FirstName", "LastName"
      from users u
        inner join friends f on u."pkUser" = f."User2ID"
      where f."User1ID"=pk

      union all

      select "pkUser", "FirstName", u."LastName" 
      from users u 
        inner join friends f on u."pkUser" = (f."User1ID") 
      where f."User2ID"=pk;
end
$$;
```

However, you can simplify the whole function to a single query and use `language sql` instead. The `return query` is not needed then.

```
create or replace function getFriends(pEmail text)
    returns TABLE(pkUser int, FirstName text, LastName text)
    language sql
as
$$

  select "pkUser", "FirstName", "LastName"
  from users u
    inner join friends f on u."pkUser" = f."User2ID"
  where f."User1ID" in (select "pkUser" 
                        from users 
                         where "Email" = pEmail)
  union all

  select "pkUser", "FirstName", u."LastName" 
  from users u 
    inner join friends f on u."pkUser" = f."User1ID"
  where f."User2ID" in (select "pkUser" 
                        from users 
                         where "Email" = pEmail);
$$;
```

Comment: Okay, that makes sense why one of my previous functions worked and this one did not. Thank you so much. Is there any what to do both of the selects that join on the Friends table?

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that those were indeed two different queries. You can combine them using UNION

Answer (score 0):

Use `SELECT ... INTO ...` to store query results

OR

open a cursor

OR

use `PERFORM ...` in the unlikely case that you don't care about the result set.